# Recovering full file path from SMB network packet

Tags: networking, wireshark, smb

I'm using WireShark to capture network information for a little network analysis project.  One of the things I would like to do is look at what files have been accessed on shared drives (that is, using the SMB protocol).

Is it possible to recover the full path name (e.g. \server\path\to\file.txt) from only the captured packet?  Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) resource, the fourth packet should contain the UNC path name, but I'm not finding it anywhere in the captured session.

If it's not possible to recover the full path from the packet alone, is there some other way using hte information in the packet?  I know, for example, that the packet contains the source IP and a file ID generated by source.  Are those helpful?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dig it in the wrong place.

You should gather and log that information within Samba Server.

If you consist to do that analyze with sniffering software,  then you have to reconstruct SMB session.

P.S. To be more specific , you need to recover all previous requests to subdirectory tree. If you need to recover \server\path\to\asdf1\file.txt, then you have to find requests to directory "to" first, also to directory "asdf1" too. Directory is a file itself, with attribite **D**.